TimeSeries Monthly average calculation
I am new to TimeSeries DB and I find hard to understand the concepts of it. I have scenario to find Time weighted average for sensor data for daily , monthly and yearly
I know there  is time_bucket available in TimeSeries. I would like to understand how we calculate the average manually for learning.
*Time                                  Value
2023-01-01 08:00:00.0000000 -07:00    1.5
2023-01-01 09:00:00.0000000 -07:00   2.5*

I used the formula 1.530/31 +2.530/31 but I get different answer than what I get from TimeSeries. Can anyone explain
